# Бесконечный список

Tags: javascript

Три вечера бился с этой проблемой, но так и не смог решить её, выявлялось все больше и больше нюансов.

Собственно суть задачи:

Есть массив (динамичный) с изображениями, блок для них, две кнопки (вперед, назад) а так же блок со всеми элементами из массива, по клику на один из них обработчик должен определить какой путь к новому элемента массива от старого будет короче (это моё соображение что бы упростить цикл, можете и по своему) (например, если всего 11 элементов, текущий индекс - 1, новый - 10. то путь до 10 будет короче в обратную сторону (0, 11, 10) а не 2, 3, 4 ... 10).

В блок кладётся от 1 до 5 (не более) элементов (4 после него и он сам), если позволяет длина массива. То есть, если текущий индекс 10, то в блоке должны быть изображения 10, 11, 0, 1, 2.

```js
let array = ["image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg","image.jpg"],

handler = (index) => {

  let current = this.current;
  
  this.current = index;
  
  /* обработчик */
  
}

this.current = 0;

back.addEventListener('click', ()=>handler(
  this.current - 1 in array ? this.current - 1 : array.length - 1
));

forward.addEventListener('click', ()=>handler(
  this.current + 1 in array ? this.current + 1 : 0
));

for (let key in array) {

  let v = array[key],
      li = document.createElement("LI");
      
  li.addEventListener('click', ()=>handler(key));
  
  all.appendChild(li);
  
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  margin: inherit;
  padding: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 48px;
  min-height: 48px;
}

#block {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}
```

```html
<ul id="block"></ul>
<button id="back">Назад</button>
<button id="forward">Вперед</button>
<ul id="all"></ul>
```

Comment: 1. отсутствует вопрос  2. то, что вам нужно называется 'карусель'  3. похожие вопросы [222 штук](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+карусель)  4. "ненужные" элементы проще прятать `hidden=true`

Comment: @qwabra 1. Вопрос раскрытые поэтому нет вопросительных знаков. 2. Нет. 4. "В блок кладётся от 1 до 5 (не более) элементов"

Comment: я рад, что вы имеете свою точку зрения по поводу первого пункта, надеюсь это поможет вам в решении проблемы

Comment: просто отслеживайте положение скрола, как только близок к концу данных запрашивайте дополнение

Answer (score 0):

проще всего использовать операцию целочисленного деления по модулю (какой там оператор для этого в JS?)

```
for (i = startIdx; i < startIdx + count; i++)
     use A[(startIdx + i) %% A.Length ]
```

при уменьшении это тоже работает, только использовать примерно так:

```
    A[(startIdx - 1 + A.Length) %% A.Length ]
```